# Thum not allowing to fire leftMouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to implement dragdrop functionality in Listbox(with in the listbox). For dragging i am using Thumb control (Mythumb is the class inherited from thumb)

so i have set the items panel to Canves and set the style for list box item to following

> ```
>            <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">                    
>                 <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
>                 <Setter Property="Height" Value="150" />
>                 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2" />
>                 <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
>                 <Setter Property="dcc:OutputConfigurationPanel.Left" Value="{Binding  Left}"></Setter>
>                 <Setter Property="dcc:OutputConfigurationPanel.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"></Setter>
>                 <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"></Setter>
>                 <Setter Property="Template">
>                     <Setter.Value>
>                         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
>                                 <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
>                                     <Grid>
>                                     <Border BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black">                                            
>                                         <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentHost" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />                                            
>                                     </Border>
>                                     <MythumbTemplate="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}" Cursor="Hand" />
>                                 </Grid>
>                                 </Grid>                                
>                             <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                                 <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
>                                     <Setter  Property="Background" Value="#FF233B00" />
>                                 </Trigger>
>                             </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                         </ControlTemplate>
>                     </Setter.Value>
>                 </Setter>
>             </Style>
> ```

The drag drop is working fine but the thumb doesn’t allow the item to be selected. After checking i found that the mousedown event is not firing.
Is there a way to enable the select the items in usual ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Thumb` will always eat mouse clicks, same as button.

As I see it, you have two options:

1. From the code of the thumb, search up until you find the list box item and then set it's `IsSelected` property to true.
2. Scrap the thumb and create a `Behavior` that deals with dragging but doesn't handle mouse events (i.e. doesn't set `e.Handled=true;`) - this will preserve list box functionality.

Option 1 is probably faster, but I'd strongly consider to go with option 2 - less meddling with core controls functionality = better.

Comment: Thanks Xameli, I too agree with your option of using behaviors. I was under the impression that Thumb was more appropriate control for Drag drop operations. But will go with behaviors. Much appreciated your response